# How can I use ISODate in NosqlUnit data set file(MongoDB)

Tags: spring-data-mongodb, fongo

I am using NosqlUnit, Fongo, Spring-Data-MongoDB

my dataset format like below.

```
{
    "people" : {
        "data" : [
            {
                "key" : "12345",
                "phone" : "33333",
                "register" : "2011-01-05T10:09:15.210Z", //It is ISODate, How can I convert Joda DateTime?
                "index" : 1
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

my domain object like this,

```
  @Id
  private ObjectId id;

  @Field("key")
  private String key;

  @Field("phone")
  private String phone;

  @Indexed(unique=true, direction=IndexDirection.DESCENDING)
  @Field("index")
  private long index;

  @Field("register")
  private DateTime register;
```

But register always null

Thanks for your help

Comment: it's perhaps a bug in fongo. Can you report an issue https://github.com/fakemongo/fongo/issues ?

Comment: @twillouer Thanks. I will report this issue

Comment: Are you trying to convert the register key output (format is ISODate) to Joda DateTime? Or are you trying to convert Joda DateTime to ISODate

Answer (score 0):

Since you didn't bother to forward the answer that was given to you [on the fongo repository issue section](https://github.com/fakemongo/fongo/issues/173)...

Use the MongoDB extended JSON strict mode notation for dates, using the ISO 8601 UTC notation (not the one with localtime and timeoffset that is [parsed incorrectly](https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/JAVA-565)), as explained [here](https://github.com/fakemongo/fongo/issues/13) and [here](https://github.com/lordofthejars/nosql-unit/issues/147):

```
{
    "people" : {
        "data" : [
            {
                "key" : "12345",
                "phone" : "33333",
                "register" : { "$date" : "2011-01-05T10:09:15.210Z" }, 
                "index" : 1
            }
        ]
    }
}
```